# Google Sheet - How to change the cell value based on a date

Tags: google-sheets

I'm looking to change a cell value according to the today's date and another requirement.

I'm creating a publication schedule on google sheet and I'm want to create a criticaly cell.

As the editorial staff gets closer to the selected publication date, the more urgent it is to react.

I would also like this "critical" cell to be able to take take in consideration another box that indicates if the article is already finished.

For example: :
A paper is due to be published on March 8. This item is not indicated as "finished". This is March 4th. There are 4 days left for the paper to be finished. I would like the "critical" box to read "high".
However, if the status box for the review says "finished" then the review box says "low".

Do you have an idea?

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Taking this sample sheet, you can use this formula to mark critical column as Low or High:

```
=IF(($B2-TODAY()<=4)*($C2<>"Finished"),"High","Low")
```

Enter this formula on the first row and drag down to the rest of the rows:

[image]

Or if you want only a single formula on D2, you can use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B<>"",IF((B2:B-TODAY()<=4)*(C2:C<>"Finished"),"High","Low"),""))
```